# Get the contents of selected textfield in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, scenebuilder

I have a number of TextFields on my UI screen and on click of a button I want to get the contents of selected textfield.I am using JavaFX and isFocused() method is not working

Answer (score 0):

The focus is moved to the `Button` before the `EventHandler` runs. This means the `TextField` is no longer focused at the time the `EventHandler` checks the property.
You could listen to the `focusOwner` property of the `Scene` though and save the last `Node` focused:

```
private static class FocusData {

    private TextField textField = null;

    public TextField getTextField() {
        return textField;
    }

    public void setFocusedNode(Node node) {
        this.textField = node instanceof TextField ? (TextField) node : null;
    }

    public boolean isTextField() {
        return textField != null;
    }

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    final FocusData focusData = new FocusData();

    Button btn = new Button("Print Text");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if (focusData.isTextField()) {
                System.out.println(focusData.getTextField().getText());
            }
        }
    });

    VBox root = new VBox();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        root.getChildren().add(new TextField());
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.focusOwnerProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Node>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> observable, Node oldValue, Node newValue) {
            focusData.setFocusedNode(oldValue);
        }
    });

    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

If you're using a fxml you can get access to the scene by adding a listener to the `scene` property of some node in the `initialize` method and add/remove the listener in that listener.

`root` is some node in the following code snippet:

```
final ChangeListener<Node> listener = new ChangeListener<Node>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Node> observable, Node oldValue, Node newValue) {
        focusData.setFocusedNode(oldValue);
    }
};

if (root.getScene() != null) {
    root.getScene().focusOwnerProperty().addListener(listener);
}

root.sceneProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Scene>() {

    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Scene> observable, Scene oldValue, Scene newValue) {
        if (oldValue != null) {
            oldValue.focusOwnerProperty().removeListener(listener);
        }
        if (newValue != null) {
            newValue.focusOwnerProperty().addListener(listener);
        }
        listener.changed(null, null, null);
    }
});
```